Is it true that $\varinjlim_{i\in I} A_i \to \varinjlim_{i\in I} B_i \to \varinjlim_{i\in I}( C_i)^*$ is an exact sequence?
$A_i\to B_i\to C_i$ be an exact sequence of abelian groups.
Let $C_i$ be a finite group. Let $I$ be directed set.
Suppose $\{A_i, f_{ji}\}, \{B_i, g_{ij}\}$ is a direct system and $\{C_i, h_{ji}\}$ is a inverse system.
Is it true that  $\varinjlim_{i\in I} A_i \to \varinjlim_{i\in I} B_i \to \varinjlim_{i\in I}( C_i)^*$ is an exact sequence ?
What kind of additional assumption ensures the theorem ?
My thought: I thought at first this is true because $\{(C_i)^*, h^*_{ji}\}$ is direct system and $(C_i)^*\cong C_i$ as groups and $\varinjlim_{i\in I}$ is an exact functor.
But I'm not confident whether we can replace a finite group in an exact sequence with its dual so easily.
Edit: Definition of $\varinjlim_{i\in I} B_i \to \varinjlim_{i\in I}(C_i)^*$ : This is an induced map by $B_i\to C_i\cong (C_i)^*$. Note that $\{B_i, g_i\}$ and $\{(C_i)^*, h_i\}$ forms direct system.

Already the assumption of the question does not work. To have an induced map on the colimits (I will not use the term "direct limit" as it is confusing), we need to have for every $i \leq j$ a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} A_i @>>> B_i @>>> C_i^* \\ @VVV @VVV @VVV \\ A_j @>>> B_j @>>> C_j^* \end{CD}$
We only have a morphism $C_j \to C_i$, and that induces a morphism $C_i^* \to C_j^*$. But you have only morphisms $B_i \to C_i$ given. You said that you are choosing isomorphisms $C_i^* \cong C_i$ and then compose $B_i \to C_i \to C_i^*$. You can do that, but not in a canonical way. In particular, the diagram will not commute.
It is very likely that the question is an attempt to prove something in a more specific context, but the question is not the "correct one" to ask. I suggest that you ask the actual, specific question instead (in a different thread).
If $(A_i) \to (B_i) \to (C_i)$ are morphisms of direct systems (this already includes the diagrams) of abelian groups, and each $A_i \to B_i \to C_i$ is exact, then indeed the induced map on the directed colimits will also be exact.

Could you provide me with a brief sketch or idea of the proof for why the right-side square doesn't become commutative?

Write down your isomorphisms concretely. Then you will see it.

I thought that for $C^* \cong C$, it was sufficient to show it when $C$ is $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ according to the structure theorem, and since $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, they were isomorphic. However, this isomorphism is not canonical, and I don't know a concrete isomorphism that would be sufficient for diagram chasing in that square diagram. So, I understand up to the point where we can't definitively claim the square  is commutative, but when it's asserted that it is not commutative, Why is that?
